# `Failed opening required 'Log.php'` trying to install

Tags: installation

I'm attempting to install CiviCRM 4.6.19 in order to perform a migration and am completely stumped on something.  This is going into a Drupal 7 site and the entire thing is being put together with Drush make.

I am attempting to load the installer at `/sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php`, which throws an error back at me - `Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Log.php'` from `path/to/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php on line 39`, which brings me to here - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.6/CRM/Core/Config.php#L39

As you can see from the rest of that directory there is no `Log.php` or `Mail.php`.  I have been trying to figure out for the last two days is something is wrong with an autoloader somewhere, and those files should already have been loaded somehow, but I am wondering if anyone knows what the heck is going on.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the Log file should be in your packages directory - if you installed from git or similar it might be missing. (I am pretty out of the loop on anything related to 4.6 though as I haven't used that version for years)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@jGrubb a number of files like Log.php and Mail.php will be from the civicrm-packages repo. This is a repo of 3rd party Packages which civicrm needs to work with. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-packages/tree/4.6

Comment: Thank you Seamus.  I'm guessing I need to clone this repo into `$pkgPath`?  Do the version tags track the civi-core version as well (ie, should I target the 4.6.19 release for the packages?)

Comment: @jgrubb Unless there's an excellent reason I would install CiviCRM from the tarball.  Installing from git is non-trivial, especially if you don't want to set up `civicrm-buildkit`.

Comment: I agree with Jon here but also @JGrubb yes the tags are the same, however if you do go down the path you are going you will need to make sure the server has a) composer and b) bower install (bower is installed using npm) then run composer install and bower install within the civicrm folder. Packages should download in to civicrm folder/packages

Comment: Thanks both.  I'd prefer to go whichever route is easiest/recommended.  Safe to assume that you are you referring to this tarball? https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/releases/tag/4.6.19 (The filesystem looks the same at a glance)

Comment: I missed my edit window, but it looks like Sourceforge would be the place for the fully integrated D7 builds (yes?).  Thank you both for the pointers.

Comment: @JGrubb that is correct and your looking for the tarball with Drupal at the end not Drupal6

Answer (score 0):

**@seamus** Lee, please In the new version of civicrm-packages ([enter link description here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-packages/tree/5.42)), those files are not included. I am using that recent version and I got the same errors as **@jGrubb** mentioned.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/11681)